# label the columns in R with count

Tags: r

I have a query on how we can get the label as `Arm 1(N=xxx)`. I am able to get the label without the numbers `(xxx)`, but is there a way in R similar to SAS to create macro variables that hold the count and later call them to resolve within the label.

What I want to do in R is that I want to get the label of columns something like consider we have column name as `ARM1` and `ARM2` and I want to get the column label as `ARM1 (N=35)` and `ARM2` column label as `ARM2 (N=20)`. So we could see the column name as `ARM1` and label as `ARM1 (N=xx)`. That number `xx` goes into the label should be dynamic as it changes depending on the data.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please make sure to add pictures directly into the question next time, without linking them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would take advantage of the non standard evaluation functionality of the dplyr package. This allows for field names changed dynamically using a mixture of the !! and := syntax.

```
df <- data.frame("Arm1"=1:10,"Arm2"=11:20)
n1 <- 20
n2 <- 40
head1 <- paste0("Arm1(N=",n1,")")
head2 <- paste0("Arm2(N=",n2,")")

#example 1
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>% 
  rename(!!head1:="Arm1",
         !!head2:="Arm2")

df2 %>% head
```

I would recommend learning more about the tidyverse packages and non standard evaluation because it can be very powerful.